# How to add a Map column to Spark dataset?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Java `Map` variable, say `Map<String, String> singleColMap`. I want to add this `Map` variable to a dataset as a new column value in Spark 2.2 (Java 1.8).

I tried the below code but it is not working:

```
ds.withColumn("cMap", lit(singleColMap).cast(MapType(StringType, StringType)))
```

Can  some one help on this?

Comment: This question is about Java, the question marked as being duplicated is about Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`typedLit`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#typedLit-T-scala.reflect.api.TypeTags.TypeTag-) that was introducted in **Spark 2.2.0**, from the documentation:

> The difference between this function and lit is that this function can handle parameterized scala types e.g.: List, Seq and Map.

So in this case, the following should be enough

```
ds.withColumn("cMap", typedLit(singleColMap))
```

Comment: i tried above option- got an error - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaUtils$SerializableMapWrapper . Can we have some other option? plz

Comment: @Sekhar: Did you use `typedLit`? There was a typo in the answer that I have corrected now.

Comment: I tried it - it is giving compile time error - expecting TypeTag. Do we have any example for this?.

Comment: @Sekhar have found solution for TypeTag ??

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be solved in Scala with `typedLit`, but I couldn't find a way to make that method to work in Java, because it requires a `TypeTag` which I don't think it's even possible to create in Java.

However, I managed to mostly emulate in Java what `typedLit` does, bar the type inference part, so I need to set the Spark type explicitly:

```java
public static Column typedMap(Map<String, String> map) {
    return new Column(Literal.create(JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(map).asScala(), createMapType(StringType, StringType)));
}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```java
ds.withColumn("cMap", typedMap(singleColMap))
```